# How to use Model::has in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":229,
         "name":"Alax",
         "age":31,
         "type":"1",
         "address":[
            {
                "id":22,
                "street_add":"14 New York",
                "country":null,
                "country": [{
                    "id":1,
                    "name":"USA",
                    "code":"US",
                    "created_at":null,
                    "updated_at":null
                }]
            }
        ]
      },
    {  
         "id":230,
         "name":"Jon",
         "age":21,
         "type":"1",
         "address":[
            {
                "id":23,
                "street_add":"25 Miami",
                "country":null,
                "country": []
            }
        ]
      }
   ]
}

if ($address) {
                Model::has('address.country', '>', 0);
            } else {
                Model::has('address.country', '<=', 0);
            }
```

Trying Model::has but does not work for me.

How can i get the address has country or not. I tried this code doesnot work for me can you please suggest on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Answer (score 0):

Just like the documentation:
[enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

```
if ($address) {
                $address = Model::has('address.country', '>', 0)->get();
            } else {
                $address = Model::has('address.country', '<=', 0)->get();
            }
```